# Which wallets or libraries besides core support (or will support) P2TR descriptors?

Tags: bip174-psbt, output-script-descriptors, p2tr, miniscript, bitcoin-development-kit

I want to help test the WIP [`Bitcoin Dev Kit`](https://bitcoindevkit.org) ["Add support for Taproot and tr() descriptors", PR #593](https://github.com/bitcoindevkit/bdk/pull/593) against other implementations besides Bitcoin Core (already testing again Core 22.0). In particular we need to test interoperability via PSBTs. BDK is based on `rust-bitcoin` and `rust-miniscript` so I'm only interested in projects not based on those libraries.

Does anyone know of any other wallet projects or libraries that support `tr()` descriptors and PSBTs that I can test with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing (May 2022) the only Bitcoin implementation other than Bitcoin Core (and Core derivatives like Knots) and rust-bitcoin I'm aware of that supports Taproot is btcd (Go). The associated btcd wallet recently [merged](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcwallet/pull/802) Taproot PSBT fields.

Wallets that support sending and receiving to P2TR addresses are listed [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption). There are some new alpha Taproot wallets popping up (e.g. [TapWallet](https://github.com/Donno1994/TapWallet)) and Kalle Alm's [btcdeb](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/btcdeb) (script debugging utilities) supports Taproot.

The site [outputdescriptors.org](https://outputdescriptors.org/) lists wallets that support descriptors generally but these may or may not yet support Taproot descriptors.

Comment: OP seems to be asking about tr() output descriptors specifically, not taproot support in general.

Comment: Ok not sure then. The hardware wallets/signers (Trezor, Ledger, Coldcard, Jade etc), wallets like Specter, Sparrow etc though maybe not yet script path tr() descriptors

Comment: As Pieter mentioned `btcsuite/btcwallet` only supports single key non-descriptor wallets, so not exactly what I'm looking for. But it does look like they support at least taproot key and script spends and PSBTs so btcsuite may be my best bet for now. At least I should be able to make a bdk `tr()` descriptor wallet that can sign a btcsuite created key or script spend PSBT. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has any better suggestions before accepting this answer.